# PowerShell Throws Exception When Running Script With Right Click Run With PowerShell

Tags: powershell, exception

I have a PowerShell script that I'm working on that runs just fine when run from within ISE and whenever I paste it into a PowerShell window and hit enter. However, whenever I right click it and click Run With PowerShell I get an exception. The exception gets thrown when a function is called.

Here is the function:

```
function GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=0)][System.Object]    $Sender,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=1)][System.EventArgs] $EventArguments,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$True, Position=2)][String]           $Text,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=3)][System.Object]   $Control1ToUpdate,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$False, Position=4)][System.Object]   $Control2ToUpdate
    )
    
    $Control1ToUpdate.Text = $Text
    $Control2ToUpdate.Text = $Text
}
```

and here are the lines of code that call the function:

```
$GUITitleTextBox_Handler = {GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged -Sender $GUITitleTextBox -EventArguments $_ -Text $GUITitleTextBox.Text -Control1ToUpdate $DefaultFormTab -Control2ToUpdate $FormLabel}.GetNewClosure()

$GUITitleTextBox.Add_TextChanged($GUITitleTextBox_Handler)
```

And this is the exception that gets thrown (only from right click Run with PowerShell, not when running in ISE or pasting it into a PowerShell window. (Path removed since it happens on multiple computers in different paths).

```
GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged : The term 'GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the
path is correct and try again.
At <Path>\PowerShell-GUI.ps1:899 char:33
+     $GUITitleTextBox_Handler = {GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged -Sender $ ...
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

What is causing this exception and how can I prevent it? This is the only function that causes an exception in the script that I've seen so far.

Comment: Make sure all of your function definitions are "on top" of the rest of the script - they won't be available for invocation until the interpreter actually reaches the `function` keyword associated with it

Comment: The function is above the call. There are no issues when I run it from ISE or pasting it into a PowerShell window. Only when running it with right click.

Comment: Can you post the full script?

Comment: It's a lengthy script (900+ lines) that won't fit in a comment. The relevant code is what I originally shared. I'm mostly looking for reasons ISE and copy-pasting it works just fine but running it through right click fails to successfully call that one function. It seems to be related to the GetNewClosure() function that allows me to pass objects to the function successfully.

Comment: This answer (for a different question) gives a workaround, but doesn't explain why it happens or if there are any other workaround options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443377/22859752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope-related issues can cause the function not to be recognized when running scripts outside of the ISE.

```
# Make sure the function is defined in the script scope
function Global:GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)][System.Object]    $Sender,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=1)][System.EventArgs] $EventArguments,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=2)][String]           $Text,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=3)][System.Object]   $Control1ToUpdate,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=4)][System.Object]   $Control2ToUpdate
    )
    
    $Control1ToUpdate.Text = $Text
    $Control2ToUpdate.Text = $Text
}

$script:GUITitleTextBox_Handler = {
    Global:GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged `
        -Sender $script:GUITitleTextBox `
        -EventArguments $_ `
        -Text $script:GUITitleTextBox.Text `
        -Control1ToUpdate $script:DefaultFormTab `
        -Control2ToUpdate $script:FormLabel
}.GetNewClosure()

$GUITitleTextBox.Add_TextChanged($script:GUITitleTextBox_Handler)
```

Prefixing the function and variable names with `Global:` ensures they are available in the global scope. The `$script:` scope modifier ensures the variables are available in the script scope where the handler is defined.

#### Also...

PowerShell can use a method or an action delegate instead of a script block to handle events in Windows Forms.

```
# Define the function
function GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged($Sender, $EventArguments) {
    $Text = $Sender.Text
    $Global:DefaultFormTab.Text = $Text
    $Global:FormLabel.Text = $Text
}

# Create an Action delegate for the TextChanged event
$TextChangedAction = [System.Action[System.Object,System.EventArgs]]::new($GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged)

# Assign the delegate to the TextChanged event
$GUITitleTextBox.add_TextChanged($TextChangedAction)
```

This approach creates a delegate that points to the `GUITitleTextBox_TextChanged` function and assigns it to the `TextChanged` event of the `$GUITitleTextBox` control. The function should be in scope when the delegate is created.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: I guess I should ask: Is there a way for PowerShell to use event handlers for Windows Forms GUI events without using a script block? Every example I've seen online for PowerShell uses the script block approach.

Comment: Thank you! So it looks like I either would need to declare all my GUI controls as global so the function can update them (delegate method) or declare all my functions as global so the script block can use them? If that's the case, I'll probably declare the functions as global since it's less reworking the script and each function has a unique name so it shouldn't have any overwriting of anything else I need.